# Pyspark org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read JSON files from a subdirectory called `world` from a S3 bucket named `hello`. When I list all the objects of that directory using boto3, I can see several part files(which were possibly created by a spark job) like below.

```
world/
world/_SUCCESS
world/part-r-00000-....json
world/part-r-00001-....json
world/part-r-00002-....json
world/part-r-00003-....json
world/part-r-00004-....json
world/part-r-00005-....json
world/part-r-00006-....json
world/part-r-00007-....json
```

I have written the following code to read all these files.

```
spark_session = SparkSession
            .builder
            .config(
            conf=SparkConf().setAll(spark_config).setAppName(app_name)
        ).getOrCreate()
hadoop_conf = spark_session._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "my-aws-access-key")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "my-aws-secret-key")
hadoop_conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3a.enableV4", "true")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")

df = spark_session.read.json("s3a://hello/world/")
```

and getting the following error

```
20/10/18 01:13:01 ERROR TaskContextImpl: Error in TaskCompletionListener
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 31439128; received: 11113005
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:172)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.abort(S3ObjectInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.close(S3AInputStream.java:199)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.close(LineReader.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.close(LineRecordReader.java:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.close(RecordReaderIterator.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.close(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext$$anon$1.onTaskCompletion(TaskContext.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$invokeListeners$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$invokeListeners$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
20/10/18 01:13:01 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Executor task launch worker for task 9
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
20/10/18 01:13:01 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/_c/gf1xl24d2y7f69vdqjthq4p40000gn/T/spark-2241418f-6797-4d06-85bb-6577b42d5d86/pyspark-58a27a10-8221-489a-b7a8-b04e29e8db60
```

I have tried with `"s3a://hello/world/*"` and `"s3a://hello/world/*.json"`as well but still getting the same error.

FYI, I am using the following versions of the tools:

```
pyspark 2.4.5
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try reading just a single json file in Spark, just to ensure your basic/aws settings are correct.

Comment: Yes, reading a single file also gives the same error. I have tried reading data with boto3 and it worked fine so the problem is not with the AWS credentials.

Comment: Use a build of spark with the hadoop-3.1 binaries to get current version of the S3A connector, see what happens next. 
That EOF exception appears to be happening in the close() call, so it's not the root cause of the problem. Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17312 to address that